# ParseQueryAdapters... Recycler Views instead?

Tags: android, parse-platform

It seems that Recycler Views are the way to go, at least from what I have been reading through documentation. But it seems that using a ParseQueryAdapter it is designed to use a listview to display data it pulls down

I have a recyclerview displaying the data in a card style look, it reads in an array with 2 strings and 1 picture per each "card" example:

```
private void initializeData(){
    persons = new ArrayList<>();
    persons.add(new Person("Emma Wilson", "23 years old", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    persons.add(new Person("Lavery Maiss", "25 years old", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
    persons.add(new Person("Lillie Watts", "35 years old", R.drawable.ic_launcher));
}
```

for this I just manually entered data in to test the card interface, how would I go about pulling fields from a query, is there a way I can setup varibles and run some sort of loop?

Would love to hear your guys thoughts...
Thanks

Comment: I want to pull data down from parse using a query and then nicely display it in a timeline

Answer (score 0):

try using ParseQuery in your intialize method

[check this out](https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#queries)

Comment: You should include in your answer the relevant content from the link you provided. If the link goes offline or is moved, your answer becomes useless.